# What are valent vertices?

Tags: terminology, reference-request, graph-theory

Page 13 of [Tropical Algebraic Geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=4JP7ofjHVh8C&lpg=PP1&ots=tWhNW0T4T4&dq=mikhalkin%20tropical%20algebraic%20geometry&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Itenberg, Mikhalkin, and Shustin mentions 1-valent vertices, but I haven't been able to find a source that actually defines this term or managed to guess the definition myself.  Either a definition or reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Valency is sometimes used in graph theory to mean the degree of a vertex, i.e. the number of edges incident on it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it so that this question won't keep popping up on the main page.

Comment: Somewhat related: in chemistry the concept of "valence" is the number of bonds one can associate to an atom, e.g. carbon has a valence of four since four single bonds can be attached to it. I have a feeling this was borrowed terminology.

Comment: ...or another way of putting it: carbon is "tetravalent". :)

Comment: I feel like I should have figured out to manipulate 'valent' to 'valency' but I guess it's clear I'm no English major.
This makes me kind of regret dodging intro chemistry all this time. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In graph theory, the *valency* of a vertex is sometimes used to mean its *degree*, i.e. the number of edges incident on it. Both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexDegree.html) mention both terms as synonyms.

Comment: A related question. Suppose a graph $G$ is 3-valent. Does that mean maximum degree of $G$ is 3, or does that mean $G$ is 3-regular? I suppose the former is correct.